# CombinedResourceHandler excluded resources doesn't recognize resources with query string

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, myfaces, omnifaces, combinedresourcehandler

I have a couple of CSS files that I don't want to combine, but I also want to bust cache for those resources, so I declared them with:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/styles.css?version=#{startup.time}" />
```

It was working fine until I added the `CombineResourceHandler`. Now the new handler does not recognize the name of the resource, and I cannot use a wildcard to exclude those resources, something like:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.COMBINED_RESOURCE_HANDLER_EXCLUDED_RESOURCES</param-name>
    <param-value>css/styles.css*</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If I remove the version parameter I have to do versioning of those files, which is something I would like to avoid.

Any ideas on how to implement this the easiest way?

Comment: `CombinedResourceHandler` has builtin cache busting. So you could just remove those from your resource names. Let me know if that's sufficient.

Comment: No, that's not sufficient, I'll try to take a look in this class to see what's going on

Comment: It's an excluded resource (I need to exclude it), so I guess that's the reasing it's not busting it.

Comment: OK, I see. Well, I just briefly looked at it, but Mojarra didn't like query strings in output style sheet resource name and just returned RES_NOT_FOUND. Perhaps you're using MyFaces? Regardless, always mention in every JSF question which JSF impl/version you are using.

Comment: Yes, I'm using myfaces. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OmniFaces identifies resources by the internal [`ResourceIdentifier`](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/resourcehandler/ResourceIdentifier.java) class. It didn't take into account any query strings, path parameters nor path fragments. As per [this commit](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/6cf71238456951cca8f18c7c2458b62ad17d9edc), this has been fixed. The fix is available in today's latest [2.2-SNAPSHOT](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/2.2-SNAPSHOT/).

Support for wildcard pattern in excluded (and suppressed) resources context param would be a good candidate for a [feature request](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues).